# Объединить метки [сеть] и [network]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c) и [network](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network). Добавить описание, что они относятся к вычислительным сетям. Русскоязычную метку сделать основной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил краткое описание для метки [сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c). Просьба проверить [предложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/151989): принять или отклонить :)